# How to get filename from Content-Disposition in headers

Tags: python, mechanize-python

I am downloading a file with Mechanize and in response headers there is a string:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myfilename.txt
```

Is there a quick standard way to get that filename value?
What I have in mind now is this:

```
filename = f[1]['Content-Disposition'].split('; ')[1].replace('filename=', '')
```

But it looks like a quick'n'dirty solution.

Comment: Just as a warning, the filename can be quoted (like most message headers) and have escape sequences.  So quick string hacks might lead to problems.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/37060344/1136400

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First get the value of the header by using mechanize, then parse the header using the builtin [cgi](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html) module.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> browser = mechanize.Browser()
>>> response = browser.open('http://example.com/your/url')
>>> info = response.info()
>>> header = info.getheader('Content-Disposition')
>>> header
'attachment; filename=myfilename.txt'
```

The header value can then be parsed:

```
>>> import cgi               
>>> value, params = cgi.parse_header(header)
>>> value
'attachment'
>>> params
{'filename': 'myfilename.txt'}
```

`params` is a simple dict so `params['filename']` is what you need.
It doesn't matter whether the filename is wrapped in quotes or not.

Comment: Not that this doesn't work if your file name is encoded, in which case the parames would contains 'filename*' instead of 'filename' and you would need to unquote and decode the filename into a unicode string.

Comment: `filename*=utf-8''file.txt` is nonstandard, see also [support encoded filename in Content-Disposition](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/67622) and [pyrfc6266](https://github.com/JohnDoee/pyrfc6266) via [how to determine the filename of content downloaded with HTTP in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060344/how-to-determine-the-filename-of-content-downloaded-with-http-in-python/73418983#73418983)

Answer (score 9):

These regular expressions are based on the grammar from RFC 6266, but modified to accept headers without disposition-type, e.g. Content-Disposition: filename=example.html

i.e. [ disposition-type ";" ] disposition-parm ( ";" disposition-parm )* / disposition-type

It will handle filename parameters with and without quotes, and unquote quoted pairs from values in quotes, e.g. filename="foo\"bar" -> foo"bar

It will handle filename* extended parameters and prefer a filename* extended parameter over a filename parameter regardless of the order they appear in the header

It strips folder name information, e.g. /etc/passwd -> passwd, and it defaults to the basename from the URL path in the absence of a filename parameter (or header, or if the parameter value is empty string)

The token and qdtext regular expressions are based on the grammar from RFC 2616, the mimeCharset and valueChars regular expressions are based on the grammar from RFC 5987, and the language regular expression is based on the grammar from RFC 5646

```
import re, urllib
from os import path
from urlparse import urlparse

# content-disposition = "Content-Disposition" ":"
#                        disposition-type *( ";" disposition-parm )
# disposition-type    = "inline" | "attachment" | disp-ext-type
#                     ; case-insensitive
# disp-ext-type       = token
# disposition-parm    = filename-parm | disp-ext-parm
# filename-parm       = "filename" "=" value
#                     | "filename*" "=" ext-value
# disp-ext-parm       = token "=" value
#                     | ext-token "=" ext-value
# ext-token           = <the characters in token, followed by "*">

token = '[-!#-\'*+.\dA-Z^-z|~]+'
qdtext='[]-~\t !#-[]'
mimeCharset='[-!#-&+\dA-Z^-z]+'
language='(?:[A-Za-z]{2,3}(?:-[A-Za-z]{3}(?:-[A-Za-z]{3}){,2})?|[A-Za-z]{4,8})(?:-[A-Za-z]{4})?(?:-(?:[A-Za-z]{2}|\d{3}))(?:-(?:[\dA-Za-z]{5,8}|\d[\dA-Za-z]{3}))*(?:-[\dA-WY-Za-wy-z](?:-[\dA-Za-z]{2,8})+)*(?:-[Xx](?:-[\dA-Za-z]{1,8})+)?|[Xx](?:-[\dA-Za-z]{1,8})+|[Ee][Nn]-[Gg][Bb]-[Oo][Ee][Dd]|[Ii]-[Aa][Mm][Ii]|[Ii]-[Bb][Nn][Nn]|[Ii]-[Dd][Ee][Ff][Aa][Uu][Ll][Tt]|[Ii]-[Ee][Nn][Oo][Cc][Hh][Ii][Aa][Nn]|[Ii]-[Hh][Aa][Kk]|[Ii]-[Kk][Ll][Ii][Nn][Gg][Oo][Nn]|[Ii]-[Ll][Uu][Xx]|[Ii]-[Mm][Ii][Nn][Gg][Oo]|[Ii]-[Nn][Aa][Vv][Aa][Jj][Oo]|[Ii]-[Pp][Ww][Nn]|[Ii]-[Tt][Aa][Oo]|[Ii]-[Tt][Aa][Yy]|[Ii]-[Tt][Ss][Uu]|[Ss][Gg][Nn]-[Bb][Ee]-[Ff][Rr]|[Ss][Gg][Nn]-[Bb][Ee]-[Nn][Ll]|[Ss][Gg][Nn]-[Cc][Hh]-[Dd][Ee]'
valueChars = '(?:%[\dA-F][\dA-F]|[-!#$&+.\dA-Z^-z|~])*'
dispositionParm = '[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee][Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\s*=\s*(?:({token})|"((?:{qdtext}|\\\\[\t !-~])*)")|[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee][Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\*\s*=\s*({mimeCharset})\'(?:{language})?\'({valueChars})|{token}\s*=\s*(?:{token}|"(?:{qdtext}|\\\\[\t !-~])*")|{token}\*\s*=\s*{mimeCharset}\'(?:{language})?\'{valueChars}'.format(**locals())

try:
  m = re.match('(?:{token}\s*;\s*)?(?:{dispositionParm})(?:\s*;\s*(?:{dispositionParm}))*|{token}'.format(**locals()), result.headers['Content-Disposition'])

except KeyError:
  name = path.basename(urllib.unquote(urlparse(url).path))

else:
  if not m:
    name = path.basename(urllib.unquote(urlparse(url).path))

  # Many user agent implementations predating this specification do not
  # understand the "filename*" parameter.  Therefore, when both "filename"
  # and "filename*" are present in a single header field value, recipients
  # SHOULD pick "filename*" and ignore "filename"

  elif m.group(8) is not None:
    name = urllib.unquote(m.group(8)).decode(m.group(7))

  elif m.group(4) is not None:
    name = urllib.unquote(m.group(4)).decode(m.group(3))

  elif m.group(6) is not None:
    name = re.sub('\\\\(.)', '\1', m.group(6))

  elif m.group(5) is not None:
    name = m.group(5)

  elif m.group(2) is not None:
    name = re.sub('\\\\(.)', '\1', m.group(2))

  else:
    name = m.group(1)

  # Recipients MUST NOT be able to write into any location other than one to
  # which they are specifically entitled

  if name:
    name = path.basename(name)

  else:
    name = path.basename(urllib.unquote(urlparse(url).path))
```

Comment: Alternatively the regular expressions can be simplified by not validating the language tag, especially since it's ignored. The language tag can contain an unbounded number of hyphens, numbers, and letters only, and it's optional. So just accept [-\dA-Za-z]*

    dispositionParm = '[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee][Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\s*=\s*(?:({token})|"((?:{qdtext}|\\\\[\t !-~])*)")|[Ff][Ii][Ll][Ee][Nn][Aa][Mm][Ee]\*\s*=\s*({mimeCharset})\'[-\dA-Za-z]*\'({valueChars})|{token}\s*=\s*(?:{token}|"(?:{qdtext}|\\\\[\t !-~])*")|{token}\*\s*=\s*{mimeCharset}\'[-\dA-Za-z]*\'{valueChars}'.format(**locals())

Answer (score 2):

The `cgi` module recommended in the top answer is slated for deprecation in Python 3.13. See [PEP594](https://peps.python.org/pep-0594/#cgi).

The official recommendation (see referenced PEP) for a standard library alternative to `cgi.parse_header` is `email.message.Message`.

And here is an example of how to get the `filename` value from a `content-disposition` header:

```py
>>> from email.message import Message
>>> content_disposition_header = 'attachment; filename=myfilename.txt'
>>> msg = Message()
>>> msg['content-disposition'] = content_disposition_header
>>> msg.get_filename()
'myfilename.txt'
```

**Note:** The above *should* work across all versions of python `>= 2.2`. The `email` package was [introduced in Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.2.html#:%7E:text=A%20new%20package%2C%20email%2C%20has%20also%20been%20added), at which point the [`Message`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.2/lib/module-email.Message.html) class API was identical to its current form insofar as the `__setitem__` and `get_filename` methods are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like:

```
import re
filename = re.findall("filename=(\S+)", f[1]['Content-Disposition'])
```

This handles quotes and URL escaping on the filenames.

Comment: But this returns a list, not a string, so you probably want `filename[0]` or something. Also it returns the quotes as part of the filename. So not really a working example.