# how to determine the filename of content downloaded with HTTP in Python?

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests, content-disposition

I download a file using the `get` function of Python [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org) library. For storing the file, I'd like to determine the filename the way a web browser would for its 'save' or 'save as ...' dialog.

Easy, right? I can just [get it from the `Content-Disposition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804799/how-to-get-pdf-filename-with-python-requests/31805472#31805472) HTTP header, accessible on the response object:

```
import re
d = r.headers['content-disposition']
fname = re.findall("filename=(.+)", d)
```

But looking more closely at this topic, it isn't *that* easy:

According to [RFC 6266 section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.3), and the grammar in the [section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-4.1), the value can be an unquoted token (e.g. `the_report.pdf`) or a quoted string that can also contain whitespace (e.g. `"the report.pdf"`) and escape sequences. Further,

> when both "filename" and "filename*" are present in a single header field value, [we] SHOULD pick "filename*" and ignore "filename".

The value of `filename*`, though, is [yet a bit more complicated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987#section-3.2.1) than the one of `filename`.

Also, the RFC seems to allow for additional whitespace around the `=`.

Thus, for the [examples listed in the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266#section-5), I'd want the following results:

- ```
    Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=example.html
  ```

  filename: `example.html`
- ```
    Content-Disposition: INLINE; FILENAME= "an example.html"
  ```

  filename: `an example.html`
- ```
    Content-Disposition: attachment;
                         filename*= UTF-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
  ```

  filename: `€ rates`
- ```
    Content-Disposition: attachment;
                         filename="EURO rates";
                         filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
  ```

  filename: `€ rates` here, too (not `EURO rates`, as `filename*` takes precedence)

Now, I could easily adapt the regular expression to account for variable whitespace around the `=`, but having it handle all the other variations, too, would get rather unwieldy. (With the quoting and escaping, I'm not even sure RegEx can cover all the cases. Maybe they can, as there is no brace-nesting involved.)

So **do I have to implement a full-blown parser, or can I determine filename according to RFC 6266 by some few calls to a HTTP library** (maybe `requests` itself)? As RFC 6266 is part of the HTTP standard, I could imagine that some libraries specialized on HTTP already cover this. (So I've [also asked on Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31836/python-library-to-get-filename-of-content-downloaded-with-http).)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`rfc6266`](https://github.com/g2p/rfc6266) library appears to do exactly what you need. It can parse raw headers, `requests` responses, and `urllib2` responses. It's on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rfc6266).

Some examples:

```
>>> import rfc6266, requests
>>> rfc6266.parse_headers('''Attachment; filename=example.html''').filename_unsafe
'example.html'
>>> rfc6266.parse_headers('''INLINE; FILENAME= "an example.html"''').filename_unsafe
'an example.html'
>>> rfc6266.parse_headers(
    '''attachment; '''
    '''filename*= UTF-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates''').filename_unsafe
'€ rates'
>>> rfc6266.parse_headers(
    '''attachment; '''
    '''filename="EURO rates"; '''
    '''filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates''').filename_unsafe
'€ rates'
>>> r = requests.get('http://example.com/€ rates')
>>> rfc6266.parse_requests_response(r).filename_unsafe
'€ rates'
```

As a note, though: this library does *not* like nonstandard whitespace in the header.

Comment: What do you mean by "nonstandard whitespace"? Whitespace at places where the standard doesn't allow whitespace? Or UNICODE whitespace that isn't part of 7-bit ASCII?

Comment: @das-g Haven't investigated enough to tell you for sure. Turns out `parse_headers` has a `relaxed` option that helps with this. Check out the code [here](https://github.com/g2p/rfc6266/blob/master/rfc6266.py#L209).

Answer (score 8):

In 2022, it seems like the Python module [rfc6266](https://github.com/g2p/rfc6266) recommended in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37060758/1083838) has been abandoned and doesn't really work with the newer versions of Python.

The good news is that there is a replacement module (One of several, but this one actually works!) called [pyrfc6266](https://github.com/JohnDoee/pyrfc6266)

It can be installed with the following:

```bash
pip install pyrfc6266
```

and used the same way:

```
import pyrfc6266
pyrfc6266.parse_filename('attachment; filename="foo.html"')
```

or

```
import requests
import pyrfc6266
response = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/response-headers?Content-Disposition=attachment;%20filename%3d%22foo.html%22')
pyrfc6266.requests_response_to_filename(response)
```

Comment: Also notable that this is MIT licensed while the abandoned lib I provided above is LGPL

Comment: to also get the `attachment` string: `value, params = pyrfc6266.parse(content_disposition); assert value == "attachment"; content_filename = next(map(lambda p: p.value, filter(lambda p: p.name == "filename", params)))`

Answer (score 2):

if you don't really need the result in utf-8

```
def getFilename(s):
  fname = re.findall("filename\*?=([^;]+)", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
  print fname[0].strip().strip('"')
```

but if utf-8 is a must

```
def getFilename(s):
    fname = re.findall("filename\*=([^;]+)", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if not fname:
        fname = re.findall("filename=([^;]+)", s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if "utf-8''" in fname[0].lower():
        fname = re.sub("utf-8''", '', fname[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        fname = urllib.unquote(fname).decode('utf8')
    else:
        fname = fname[0]
    # clean space and double quotes
    print fname.strip().strip('"')

# example
getFilename('Attachment; filename=example.html')
getFilename('INLINE; FILENAME= "an example.html"')

getFilename("attachment;filename*= UTF-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates")
getFilename("attachment; filename=\"EURO rates\";filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates")

getFilename("attachment;filename=\"_____ _____ ___ __ ____ _____ Hekayt Bent.2017.mp3\";filename*=UTF-8''%D8%A7%D8%BA%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%87%20%D8%AD%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9%20%D8%A8%D9%86%D8%AA%20%D9%84%D9%80%20%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%20%D8%B4%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%A9%20Hekayt%20Bent.2017.mp3")
```

result

```
example.html
an example.html
€ rates
€ rates
اغنيه حكاية بنت لـ محمد شحاتة Hekayt Bent.2017.mp3
```

Comment: If the string `utf-8` is not in the beginning should it be treated differently? If the header is `"attachment;filename*= UTF-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates UTF-8'' here"` or `"attachment;filename*= @UTF-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates @UTF-8'' here"?