# Reliable way of parsing a Content-Disposition header

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, http-headers

[`rfc6266`](https://github.com/g2p/rfc6266) used to be the perfect tool for this job, but it is no longer working as of recently because of various issues.
The latest [fork](https://github.com/SWW13/python-rfc6266-parser) fixes some of it, but still leaves some unaddressed. Such as the fact that LEPL, a package that rfc6266 depends on, has been [abandoned](http://www.acooke.org/lepl/discontinued.html) and is no longer [compliant](https://github.com/SWW13/python-rfc6266-parser/issues/2) with Python 3.5+.

So is there a clean and reliable method for parsing a Content-Disposition header that is still working today?

Note: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060344/how-to-determine-the-filename-of-content-downloaded-with-http-in-python) for issues that can't be easily solved (at least in my opinion) by using a quickly hacked together ad-hoc parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parser from werkzeug to do this. Its not as thorough, but it does the trick for flask and quart. See: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/main/src/werkzeug/http.py#L377