# Python 3, cgi.parse_header

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to use python to automatically download files from various websites. I am using python 3.8 and LinuxMint.  The code I use works well in most instances but there are couple where I get an error message.  If I manually visit the website, I can download and save the files in question with no problem.  While doing manual downloading of the files, I noticed that one website uses a hyphen in the file name (driv_full-holdings_20210830.csv) and the other puts a space at the end of the file name, right before the dot+extension (SMOG_asof_20210830 .xlsx). My hunch is that the hyphen and space in the file names are what is causing the error. How can I automate downloading these files? Here is the code I am using and the error generated:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import cgi

url = "https://www.vaneck.com/etf/equity/smog/holdings/download/xlsx/"

path = ('/home/edmint/2results/holdingPen/')

remotefile = urlopen(url)
blah = remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']
value, params = cgi.parse_header(blah)
filename = params["filename"]
urlretrieve(url, (path + filename))


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-da0bd24b8e15> in <module>
      1 remotefile = urlopen(url)
      2 blah = remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']
----> 3 value, params = cgi.parse_header(blah)
      4 filename = params["filename"]
      5 urlretrieve(url, (path + filename))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/cgi.py in parse_header(line)
    231 
    232     """
--> 233     parts = _parseparam(';' + line)
    234     key = parts.__next__()
    235     pdict = {}

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

The other url I am trying this at is

https://www.globalxetfs.com/funds/driv/?download_full_holdings=true

and the resulting error message is identical.

TIA

Comment: the `cgi` module is deprecated: `DeprecationWarning: 'cgi' is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.13`. an alternative is [pyrfc6266](https://github.com/JohnDoee/pyrfc6266). see also [how to determine the filename of content downloaded with HTTP in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73418983/10440128)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is `remotefile.info()['Content-Disposition']` is `None`, which then causes the above error when trying to concatenate the input to a string when trying to parse the header. You should probably check to see if the header is provided: a quick check of the available headers shows `Content-Disposition` isn't present, which you can verify with `print(dict(remotefile.info())`.

We get the same exact error if we pass `None` to `parse_header`.

```
In [46]: cgi.parse_header(None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-0f5409738ee2> in <module>
----> 1 cgi.parse_header(None)

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\cgi.py in parse_header(line)
    227
    228     """
--> 229     parts = _parseparam(';' + line)
    230     key = parts.__next__()
    231     pdict = {}
```

Printing the contents of the headers, we can see that header is not provided:

```
>>> print(dict(remotefile.info()))
{'x-amz-id-2': 'w22MoEI/cjaJLgujA8A7eG8n9B5RCinHeVUMJGnk88mxrO/qW/TTuL68Ow0iRQTinytsRE1Mi7w=',
 'x-amz-request-id': 'WSR5HXX9FBGTNBHZ',
 'Date': 'Mon, 06 Sep 2021 02:31:20 GMT',
 'Last-Modified': 'Fri, 03 Sep 2021 10:03:12 GMT',
 'ETag': '"2b7d2ef6276c171712a7e5899a734f30"',
 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
 'Content-Type': 'binary/octet-stream',
 'Server': 'AmazonS3',
 'Content-Length': '5740',
 'Connection': 'close'}
```

You must check the header is provided before passing it to `parse_header`. The above code was run on the URL `https://www.globalxetfs.com/funds/driv/?download_full_holdings=true`, which you provided in your example.

Comment: I devised 2 workarounds using wget with 1st url and a modification of the code I originally posted for the 2nd url. 2 questions: In Spyder & Jupyter in Anaconda-Navigator I tried to use "print(dict(remotefile.info())" but only received errors.  I tried it quite a few different ways but never got the output you posted. I tried it in a python terminal window but the only response was ". . .".  In which environment did you use "print(dict(remotefile.info())" and are those the exact characters you used?  2.) If you wished to download from these urls, which methods/packages would you use?

Comment: @KalaDude I'm missing one close parenthesis, but that's a minor error. Ofc, the actual output will vary slightly, but you will get the same type of headers. The main issue is that the header you are expecting is not provided. You cannot parse a header that does not exist.

Comment: As far as the `value, params = cgi.parse_header(...)`, you never actually use those values. You don't **need** the content disposition if you're downloading files, since it has no relationship to what you're using it for. `Content-Disposition` denotes whether it's meant to be displayed in a browser or downloaded, but you want to download it regardless. You don't actually want the output of the header. You don't need the header: just delete the `cgi.parse_header` lines.

Comment: If you wanted to know the content type of a file you were downloading that wasn't obvious, then we might have an entirely different story: then there's a clear example of where your code might want to error or skip the file. If you don't know if the file provided is a PDF, text file, etc. and there may be no magic numbers to denote that, if `Content-Type` is not provided, you may want to actually consider that. But... `Content-Disposition` does not relate to what your code is doing. I'm not sure why you're using it.

Comment: Yes, I did understand that I can not parse a header that doesn't exist, that's what clued me to my workarounds. Thank-you.  Still wondering which packages or methods you would have use in this instance.

Comment: I would have used the exact same tools, just probably `requests` rather than `urllib`, and then done exactly what you did above, but ignored the whole header parsing since it's unrelated to the task at hand.

Comment: If you're doing something very simple, a bash script with wget works, for anything more complicated I tend to use `requests` and Python.