# How to get file name from a URL when content-disposition is missing in headers using python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I trying to automate downloading a bunch of pdfs. Among others, one URL is as follows

https://www.unpri.org/download?ac=4195

I'm using the following code to get the headers from this URL

```
import requests

h = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
header = h.headers

print(header)
```

These are the headers
`{'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}`

There is no content-disposition or anything else that can give me file name. However, when I open this in the browser and right click --> save as, I get option to save with its original name(screenshot below)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g0l8.png)

Is there any way I can get this file name with python?

Comment: You mean you're gettting `< Content-disposition: inline; filename=PRI_Investor_guide_on_agricultural_supply_chain.pdf ` in your headers response? If yes, can you please share your code or versions of the libraries used? 

As a last resort, I can use `download_ac=4195` from URL but ideally I would like to extract the proper name as browser already has it

Comment: You're right I'm also getting the content-disposition header on CMD. I also tested it with [Redbot](https://redbot.org/?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unpri.org%2Fdownload%3Fac%3D4195) and this also gives the disposition header in response. Probably, a problem with **requests** library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add proper `User-Agent` and use the response headers to get the file name.

Here's how:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:95.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/95.0",
}

r = requests.get("https://www.unpri.org/download?ac=4195", headers=headers)
print(r.headers["Content-disposition"].split("=", -1)[-1])
```

Output:

```
PRI_Investor_guide_on_agricultural_supply_chain.pdf
```

Comment: `import cgi`, `value, params = cgi.parse_header(header)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035900/how-to-get-filename-from-content-disposition-in-headers#27840405, pyrfc6266 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37060344/how-to-determine-the-filename-of-content-downloaded-with-http-in-python/37060758#37060758